# SonarQube Web-API - api/resources not returning all projects

Tags: sonarqube

I use the following url to extract a number of metrics for each of the projects we have in SonarQube:

```
/api/resources?metrics=lines,ncloc,reliability_rating, ...
```

But, it is missing data for (at least) one of the projects. But if I use the following:

```
/api/resources?resource=69644
```

It will pull the data for the project. What would cause the project to not show up in the first use case?

We are currently on SonarQube 5.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question...

Turns out this particular endpoint has a hard coded limit of 500 components. Which is a known issue and will not be fixed and the endpoint has been deprecated.

To get the same functionality I've switched to using `api/projects/index` to get the list of projects and then use `api/measures/component` for each project I'm interested in getting metrics for.